# MySQL Query returns smaller value for a larger than where clause

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the query

> SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE id = '7883c2c8e6' AND value >  '45' DESC

But for some reason it is returning a row where the value for the field value is 8. I have checked and it has not preceding or following characters. The field is currently set as varchar. I was wondering if this could affect the outcome?

If I change the direction of the > to < this row does not show up, but it should be the other way round surely?

Comment: If you want to order by values, make the `value` a numeric column, either `INT` or `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL`. Now it's a `CHAR` (I assume) and the `<` compares lexicographically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because '8' is greater than '45' (in alphabetical order).

[Cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) your values to int:

```
AND convert( value, unsigned) > 45
```

Comment: `convert( value, int )` will FAIL! `convert( value, UNSIGNED) ` will not. Also, the `DESC` isn't allowed there.

Comment: @RossSmithII, fixed. Thanks. This is embarrassed.

Comment: No need to feel embarrassed. I've made the same mistake so many times, I've lost count!

Answer (score 1):

`The field is currently set as varchar`

That's the issue; if you use a comparison operator on a text field, it will sort the results alphabetically, rather than numerically.

To get around it, set the field to be an integer instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE id = '7883c2c8e6' AND (value * 1) > 45
order by value DESC
```